# Domain Masking with Azure web app will work or not

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I hosted my website on azure web app, and custom domain(goddy) mapping done, I also created new deployment slot and hosted another site on same web app in azure, it's working on azure by default link, But i created sub domain on goddy and I want to redirect my second web site on sub domain link, can any one suggestme , domain masking will work here or not.
My both website in different technology, I want to use single web app in azure, Please suggest.

Comment: First off, it is possible to use a custom domain with only your production slot. If you want to deploy multiple site into one web, you can create a VM and publish your sites into the VM.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of hosting two different applications on the same web app? Do they have common app settings/common configuration values?  If apps are in 2 different technologies, its not recommended to host them in single azure web app. You may create another azure web app and set it up to use the same `app service plan` so your 2 azure web apps will use the same app service plan which means **no extra cost**. Slots are there to host different environments of the same web application.